# How to interface LCD for new WaRP7 (imx7s-solo)?

Tags: x11, drivers, embedded, interface, yocto

I'm trying to interface LCD for my new WaRP (imx7s-solo). (we can found both LCD and WaRP7 here [LCD and WaRP7 product](https://www.element14.com/community/docs/DOC-87448/l/warp7-lcd-module)) The problem is I can not have enough knowledge to verify my work is right or wrong. (I'm an application developer actually...). My work are below:

First try: I build & install core-image-sato on board. After checking boot log, I see there are driver is loaded, the result is LCD is ON but only white screen. Logs are
backlight supply power not found, using dummy regulator
MIPI DSI driver module loaded

30760000.mipi-dsi supply disp-power-on not found, using dummy regulator mxc_mipi_dsi_samsung 30760000.mipi-dsi: i.MX MIPI DSI driver probed MIPI DSI driver module loaded

30730000.lcdif supply lcd not found, using dummy regulator mxc_mipi_dsi_samsung 30760000.mipi-dsi: MIPI DSI dispdrv inited!
mxsfb 30730000.lcdif: registered mxc display driver mipi_dsi_samsung
Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 40x40
mxsfb 30730000.lcdif: initialized

Next I tried to build and run few things to check that I can display something on screen before continue to work. use some commands "startx", "cp /dev/urandom /dev/fb0"..etc but screen still remains white only.
Other tried, I run Qt Helloworld application on WaRP7 and it keep showing error "Bus error" nothing more....
=> If possible, please help me clarify few thing

which is the right path should I follow ?

with the steps above, is there any chance or additional step to display something on LCD (console or anything)

Note: this is only the most positive way (I think). I've google-ed it & try many other ways for weeks. (For example: use fbtft notro driver, writing driver....etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am currently working on the LCD Display integration on the WaRP7, and it's working well but not yet merged on the linux-warp7 kernel. I maintain the official Yocto/OE layer for WaRP7 (with some examples), and there are some features for LCD have been already merged.

I just opened a pull request to push the unofficial patch (until the official patch is merged): https://github.com/WaRP7/meta-warp7-distro/pull/37